# Prove that the set of integers modulo m is precisely {[0], [1],...,[m-1]}

Tags: congruences

I need to prove that each of the congruence classes listed above are different, and that any other congruence class [a](for any integer a) has to be equal to one of the congruence classes listed.

I know in order to prove the second part I must show that a is a subset of a congruence class and that congruence class is a subset of a to show they're equal but I'm not sure how to go about the first part.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The congruence class of an integer is the congruence class of its remainder when divided by $m$. Two remainders can't be congruent, since they're their own remainders. What is the list of the possibles remainders?

Comment: I need to show that each congruence class in {[0], [1], ..., [m-1]} are actually different

Comment: Remainder in Euclidean division is unique. Thus $[i]\ne [j]$ if $\;0\le i,j<m$ and $i\ne j$.

Comment: i still dont understand how to prove that each congruence class is different

Comment: Two integers are in the same congruence class if they have the same remainder when divided by $m$. Do two distinct natural numbers less than $m$ have the same remainder?